# I'm moving DNS control to another AWS account. What to do with the SOA record?

Tags: amazon-route53

When I move DNS control for domains I buy from namecheap.com to AWS then I simply copy the NS records provided when I create the hosted zone in Route53 and replace the namecheap.com NS records with these.

I tried the same thing with moving DNS control from one AWS account to another, however this is not working. A dig query shows the new NS records in the target hosted zone, however ping queries fail indicating that the DNS server cannot be found for the specified host. (There is definitely an A name record for the host)

Following the [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/MigratingDNS.html), I replaced the NS records in the old zone with the NS records that Route53 automatically creates in the new zone. These instructions also say "Do not create additional ... start of authority (SOA) records in the Amazon Route 53 hosted zone, and do not delete the existing ... SOA records.". It doesn't say what I should edit them as, but if I understand the SOA record, I believe I should update the SOA record in the original zone to point to the first NS in the new zone. That way the SOA records in each zone would also be identical ...yes?

When I [update namecheap.com to transfer DNS control to AWS](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/767/10/how-can-i-change-the-nameservers-for-my-domain), I simply set "Custom DNS" then plug in the AWS NS records. I think internally namecheap.com updates their copy of the SOA record automatically because I dont need to do anything with the SOA record and it just works.

Comment: Changing the NS records in a Route 53 hosted zone does not change which name servers Route 53 has assigned to the zone.  Is that what you did, edit the NS records in the new zone in the new account?

Comment: @sqlbot.. nope. I edited the post to add more info on what I did do.

Comment: You can't bounce an entire domain from one hosted zone to another except when doing a delegation at the subdomain level... DNS doesn't work that way. There are only two steps required, and nothing needs to change in the old zone.  1. Create new hosted zone and populate with A, MX, etc. records.  2. Change the configuration *at the registrar* to set the authoritative nameservers for the domain to point to the NS records for the new zone.

Comment: AWS *is the registrar*. Hence "Change the configuration at the registrar to set the authoritative nameservers for the domain to point to the NS records for the new zone." ... is what I have done .. by going into Route53 in the account where the domain name is purched, and changing the NS records to be the same as the NS records in the new Hosted Zone of the other AWS account.  SOA records remain unchanged which does not seem to make sense.

Comment: Ah... it's not telling you to change the NS records... you need to change the *authoritative name servers* with the Route 53 Registrar.  In the console, click "Registered Domains," select your domain, then choose "add/edit name servers."  Change *those* records to the name servers from the new hosted zone.  Once the hosted zone in the new account is authoritative, you can delete the hosted zone in the old account.  There's no need to change anything in the old hosted zone because it will not have any function once the authoritative nameservers are changed to point away from it.

Comment: Yup. I just purchased my first domain through AWS to see what they really have. ( I was doing this over Slack with a customer who purchased the domain, so I never really knew what he was looking at ) Turns out there is a button at the top that says "Manage DNS" at the top which takes you to the hosted zone and NS records .. but that is not correct. There is *another* section to the right (the one you are referring to) where there are also NS records and *those* are the ones to change.  The NS records you get to from the "Manage DNS" button is a bit of a red herring IMHO